# Can I set the gold linker as the default one?

Tags: package-management, symbolic-link, binutils

Before Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy), the `/usr/bin/ld` symlink was pointing to `ld.gold` when the `binutils-gold` package was installed. Gold now comes with the `binutils` package itself, and it installs the `/usr/bin/ld` symlink pointing to `ld.bfd`. Is there some hard reason for that? Since I need to use gold, can I change the symlink? Is it going to break something?

Comment: I think it'd breaks things, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3476562/2319964

Comment: @Donarsson upvote for the link

Comment: I edited the question to make it not specific to saucy. It is still a valid question for newer Ubuntu releases, so please consider reopening.